# Pandas conditional calculation based on values in other column

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index, calculation, cryptocurrency

I need to calculate pct_change for Bitcoin (BTC) and Ether (ETH) prices from this data frame:

[image: data frame of BTC and ETH closing prices]

The formula I want to use is basically:

```
initial = df['Close'][0]
final = df.iloc[-1]['Close']

df['Performance'] = (100*(df[symbol] - initial)/initial)
```

The problem is, I can't figure out how to keep BTC and ETH calculations separate. How can I do this? I tried making two separate data frames, one for BTC and one for ETH and then using the formula, but I got this error:

*A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead*

What can I do instead?

Comment: try this `df2.groupby('level_1')['Close'].pct_change()`

Comment: and next time make example code or text not image

Answer (score 0):

Try with those lines. Read more about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas).

```
import pandas as pd

pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None  # default='warn'
```